# Selenium print list from find elements

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using find_element*S*_by_xpath I got a list successfully mapped to the price varibale and I would like to print that out. I know I have iterate through since its a list however the actual text of the xpath doesn't want to print properly:

my code:

```
price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='price']")

for x in range (len(price)):
    print(price[x])
    driver.quit()
```

results are these instead of the actual text:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="45e318bd282a63442a83df978a1aa85d", element="bbfc9091-7332-4ca4-8480-7ace07ea5cbb")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="45e318bd282a63442a83df978a1aa85d", element="3db3e802-ac72-4dd1-8a3e-748950082f10")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="45e318bd282a63442a83df978a1aa85d", element="01cbbcf5-413e-4817-aaef-e4f70655a7fa")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="45e318bd282a63442a83df978a1aa85d", element="7e4132f7-21ca-4364-b462-7ef9b4ffe0c4")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="45e318bd282a63442a83df978a1aa85d", element="511435cb-d259-4f78-bddb-9ceb2f666636")>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.text` to print the value.

```
price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='price']")

for x in range (len(price)):
    print(price[x].text)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks. With that I did move forward and I got the first element of the list printed out successfully but after the first it throws a traceback error " response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)

 NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x120d72220>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused"

Comment: @user3916 : You need to put  `driver.quit()` out side for loop.You kept it inside for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use getText() to display the value:

```
    List<WebElement> price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='price']");
    for(WebElement x : price)
        print(x.getText());
```